# Is git ls-files really character agnostic? If not, what is?

Tags: git, utf-8

I'm working in Mac OS 10.6 with git version 1.7.0 .

If I execute

```
echo "" > frëd   # that's f r \xEB d
git ls-files --other 'f*'
```

I get back

```
"fre\314\210d"                     # that's 14 characters including two \'s
```

whereas `ls f*` reports

```
frëd                               # 4 characters, 5 bytes
```

This causes poor behaviour in magit-status mode in Emacs.

How can I work around this and have git ls-files report the same way
that ls does, without interpreting the bytes of the filename?

-- David

Comment: Interesting ... `e\314\210` when you transform it assuming UTF8 into UNICODE code points, you get `"e\u0308"` which is `e` followed by an [umlaut diacritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut_(diacritic)) which is probably a valid UNICODE decomposition.  Try setting your `LANG` environment variable to `en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: If you're working in Mac OS 10.6, I find it hard to believe that you actually managed to write "f r \xEB d" to the Filesystem.  It really really strongly wants to use UTF-8, and everything is set up for that.

Comment: Its not that it wants to use UTF-8, it wants to *normalize* all Unicode usage by changing all precomposed characters into a normal character followed by a combining diacritical mark. Both are valid Unicode and UTF-8, but Mac OSX forces it to be a certain way.

Answer (score 5):

Git escapes the filename so that it doesn't contain any hard to interpret characters like terminal sequences, common separators like newline, etc. So does (gnu) `ls` by the way, but here `ls` is more tolerant. You can use the `-z` flag to get the original names in a zero-terminated, machine-parsable format. Magit should use it (parsing escapes is more fragile), patch it if you can.